# BackboneJS Magnific Popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, popup

I have this Backbone App where I want to use the `Magnific Popup` for my login. So I created a View

```
var userTopNavigation = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        className : 'nm',
        template: 'userNavigationItem',
        events: {
            'click .login': 'login',
        },
        login: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.login').magnificPopup({
                disableOn: 700,
                type: 'inline',
                removalDelay: 160,
                preloader: false,
                fixedContentPos: false
            });
        }
});
```

My HTML-userNavigationItem template looks like:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="login">
      <span class="navpptxt">Login</span>
  </a>  
</li>
```

Then on my index.php I placed the popup:

```
<div id="loginbox" class="white-popup mfp-hide">...some content here...</div>
```

So I can see that the `Magnific popup`-script is loaded and the only thing what happens is that when I click the `<a href="#" class="login">` - the Modal bagground gets loaded, but not my popup!!?

What could be the issue here? Do i have to place the popup div somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You want to call the loginbox with the magnific popup, not the login button:
        $('#loginbox').magnificPopup({

Comment: Did you render the template on initialize?

Try to use the example i made [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jJfV7/)

Comment: No, no effect, I dont think it has something to do with that?

Comment: Can you fiddle the page? put it online so i can see it?